# How to Allow users to add a choice not in django Choices list

Tags: django, forms

When giving users a choice of things to choose in choices list for a model, if they do not find the choice they are looking for, how can you make them add a new one, and store their choice as the value they added.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for what you want to do, if you want that all the users can have the new choice, you have to save everything in a model and take out the choices from there, if you want to have a "preset of variables" and then just save the new one just for your user, just save the new one in the user choice in a charfield directly, if you tell me what approach you want, I can give you a more extensive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what choices on a field are made for. They are used for a *set of choices that does not change if the code does not change*.

If you need choices that can be modified without modifying the code, the natural approach is to use the database. A foreign key is the right tool to use:

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender)
```

In your admin.py:

```
from .models import Gender
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Gender, admin.ModelAdmin)
```

Now admins can add extra genders, which will be available for all.